# Few apps suddenly not opening in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Few of the applications IntelliJ, Notepad ++, VLC and Google Chat are not opening suddenly. I restarted the laptop and try to launch from Launcher. Even no luck, just some small loading icon appearing for 10 to 15 seconds and after nothing. It happened 4 bays back, I stop using them.

[image]

Comment: Did you try checking for updates on apps?

Comment: (1) There is no question in your "question". As this is a Q&A site, what is your question? "Why?" is different than "how can I fix?"; pick one. (2) Do these programs report errors when you run them in a command line? I mean in a shell inside a GUI terminal emulator where things like `$DISPLAY` should be set correctly without you worrying about it. What are the errors. Please [edit] the question and post them. E.g. I can run `LC_ALL=C vlc` to see errors (if any) in English.

Answer (score 0):

Luckily, I resolved myself. The problem was, that `snap` does not exist, but I don't know why it was missed. I reinstalled snap. Everything started working...

Answer (score 0):

In my case what I was done wrong, was that I had changed the `/dev/shm` permeation!
I was trying to mount a Postgres container inside `/dev/shm` and I accidentally gave the address as `/dev/shm` not something like `/dev/shm/my-pg`.

#### How I figured it out?

`google-chrome-stable` in the terminal saved me!

All I had to do was to change the permeation:

`sudo chmod 1777 /dev/shm`